# Hudson CLI, anyone got it to work?

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, hudson

I simply could not get it to work not matter what. The only thing it does is that it lists the help. that's all. Any help, example is appreciated. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Debian package (then the prerequisite package `daemon` to get it to finish installing), then got the jarfile from the warfile according to instructions, and it works for me:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ java -jar /usr/local/bin/hudson-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ version
2.0.1
jcomeau@intrepid:~$ java -jar /usr/local/bin/hudson-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ list-changes
Argument "JOB" is required
java -jar hudson-cli.jar list-changes args...
Dumps the changelog for the specified build(s)
 JOB                         : Name of the job to build
 RANGE                       : Range of the build records to delete. 'N-M',
                               'N,M', or 'N'
 -format [XML | CSV | PLAIN] : Controls how the output from this command is
                               printed.
```